# Loop Nested Maps - Double result

Tags: java, nested

I am new in Java, and trying to understand Nested Maps,  exactly how I can filter unnecessary result from loop.

```
Map<String,Map<Integer,Integer>> add = new LinkedHashMap<>();
Map<Integer,Integer> add2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();

for(Map.Entry<String,Map<Integer,Integer>> view: add.entrySet()){
    System.out.println("Name: " + view.getKey());

    for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>view2: add2.entrySet()){
        System.out.println("Number: "+ view2.getKey());
        System.out.println("ID:"+ view2.getValue());
        System.out.println("==================");
    }
}
```

The result with:Name1,1234 and Name2,2345
is:

```
Name: Name1
Number: 1234
ID:1
Number: 2345
ID:2 
====================
Name: Name2
Number: 1234
ID:1 
Number: 2345
ID:2
```

I want only result for: name 1, number 1, ID1 without Number2 and ID2 on first loop... 
Or how to iterate this without double number and ID?

-->
When i put 3 Names, with 3 numbers for each one name, for the first One i get:

```
Name: name1

Number: 111
ID:1
===============
Number: 2222
ID:2
===============
Number: 3333
ID:3
===============
```

and for others is the same

```
Name: name2

    Number: 111
    ID:1
    ===============
    Number: 2222
    ID:2
    ===============
    Number: 3333
    ID:3
    ===============
```

should be just

```
Name 1
Number: 111
ID:1
============

Name 2
Number: 222
ID:2
============

Name 3
Number: 333
ID:3
```

Comment: Can you be more specific please?what values do you have in `add`, what in `add2` and what is your expected result?

Comment: Replace `add2.entrySet()` ==> `view.getValue().entrySet()` in the header of the nested loop. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Name: Name1
Number: 1234
ID:1
========
Name: Name2
Number: 2345
ID:2

Answer (score 0):

This is how you iterate over a nested `Map`:

```
Map<String,Map<Integer,Integer>> add = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for(String key : add.keySet()) {
    for(Integer key : add.get(key).keySet()) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

You missed the `add.get(key).keySet()` part in your code.

Comment: When i put 3 Names, with 3 numbers for each one name, for the first One i get:

    Name: name1
    
    Number: 111
    ID:1
    ===============
    Number: 2222
    ID:2
    ===============
    Number: 3333
    ID:3
    ===============

and for others is the same 

    Name: name2
        
        Number: 111
        ID:1
        ===============
        Number: 2222
        ID:2
        ===============
        Number: 3333
        ID:3
        ===============

should be just 

    Name 1
    Number: 111
    ID:1

Comment: its not working like that: add.get(key).keySet(), again i have repeating of other information

Answer (score 0):

to know about iterating nested map read this [A better way to iterate java maps](http://jtoee.blogspot.in/2008/05/better-way-to-iterate-java-maps.html)

You can iterate over the keys in a map using the **[Map.keySet()](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/12/how-to-traverse-or-loop-hashmap-in-java.html)** method.
Also go through [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29) link.

Comment: about Iterating, I did it, but stil have same result.